# React-Redux Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The github repo for this project: https://github.com/leongaban/react_starwars

#### Expected

My basic app runs without errors, and in the chrome devtools Redux tab, I see a list of star wars characters

#### Results

[image]

The main index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './components/App'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reducer from './reducer'
import { getCharacters } from './reducer/characters/actions'

const store = createStore(reducer, compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension : f => f
));

store.dispatch(getCharacters())

const container = document.getElementById('app-container');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
, container);
```

My src > reducer > characters > actions.js

```
import { API_URL } from '../../constants'

export const SET_CHARACTERS = 'SET_CHARACTERS'

export function getCharacters() {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch(`${API_URL}/people`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => res.results)
            .then(characters => 
                dispatch(setCharacters(characters))
            )
    }
}

export function setCharacters(characters) {
    return {
        type: SET_CHARACTERS,
        characters
    }
}
```

reducer > characters > index.js

```
import { SET_CHARACTERS } from './actions'

const initialState = [];

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_CHARACTERS:
            return action.characters;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

reducer > index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import characters from './characters'

export default combineReducers({
    characters
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
const createFinalStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
)(createStore)

const store = createFinalStore(reducer, initialState /* or {} */);
```

i don't think the createStore redux api wants you to pass the middleware as the second argument. that should be the initial/preloaded state

http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea why the author of the tutorial I was watch added that strange `window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension : f => f` line. That made no sense to me.

Comment: AH! It was for the Redux Chrome dev extension and it needed to be `const store = createStore(reducer, compose(
 applyMiddleware(thunk),
 window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
));`

Comment: yup, there's nothing wrong with adding that, was just in the order you construct the store / pass args